# Javascript Using Local Storage, calling back the object and changing with Json to a string to use in a populate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms, populate

Hello I am doing a form and I used a populate method to fill a form out in jJQuery (Yes I know jquery is just a library) for testing. Now I save the data in the form using Json and Local Storage. Then I call back the object in local storage and use Json to turn it back into a string. The problem is the string will be the EXACT same as the string i hard coded into the populate method but when I put the string to replace it (so its always using current form saved data) it will not work correctly. I'm assuming it is something small.

This is my object called back from local storage and turned back into a string.

```
var myString = localStorage.getItem("all");
var myStringSave = JSON.stringify(myString); //my string
```

myStringSave will contain for example:
    Name:'Joe',dateBirth:'01/02/1992'
Which is the exact same as my hard coded one. However hardcoded works

```
$('#frm').populate({Name:'Joe',dateBirth:'01/02/1992'})
```

But the one in the string will not work:

```
$('#frm').populate(myStringSave)
```

or

```
$('#frm').populate({myStringSave})
```

I have been looking at it for a few hours and it makes no sense. The string is the exact same as my hard coded one, so why does it not work? Thank you any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[populate](http://davestewart.io/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html) accepts a JSON as parameter, and you give it a string.

> The basic form for using Populate is: $(selector).populate(JSON,
>   options)

Don't do :

```
var myString = localStorage.getItem("all"); // this IS a string (localStorage can't store anything else)
var myStringSave = JSON.stringify(myString); // you stringify a string
```

You can get your JSON back by using :

```
myJsonSave = JSON.parse( localStorage.all )
```

Then `$('#frm').populate(myJsonSave)` should work.

You can even do it all in one line :

`$('#frm').populate( JSON.parse( localStorage.all ) )`

Comment: I tried those together and it still keeps the form blank

Comment: What does `console.log(myJsonSave)` output? Also, any other errors in the console?

Comment: Your 'all in one line' worked perfectly. I'm not sure why the other one did not. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ah nice. Are you sure you didn't write `populate({myJsonSave})` instead of `populate(myJsonSave)`? I made a typo and corrected it afterwards, maybe you copied the wrong code.

Comment: Just tested ya that was the case. The way I did it I used string replace a few times in a loop. Which is how I checked my Json parameter, and I did add and replace those { } a few times, that's probably why I didn't notice. Thanks a lot again. If I can get your opinion is this a good question? Could I make it better? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah I think this is a good question, not too short, not too long, you posted just the relevant code, and that was enough to solve the problem. Congrats =)